# Understanding tidyr::gather key/value arguments

Tags: r, tidyr

Simple question,

I've provided two different data frames below with code/output, why does one work and the other doesn't? Having trouble understanding the Key/Value inputs (when they need to be explicitly defined/and what it means to just have them as strings in the input).

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(one = c("x", "x", "x"), two = c("x", "", "x"), 
                   three = c("", "", ""), type = c("chocolate", "vanilla", "strawberry")) 

dat %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  gather("Key", "Val", -type,na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  rowid_to_column  %>%
  spread(Key, Val,fill = "") %>%
  select(-1) # works well 

dat %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  gather("Key", "Val", -type,na.rm=TRUE) 
Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: Val
```

Extra Credit: if someone could explain the effect of `rowit_to_column` & `spread()`, that'd be helpful.

Comment: I think offering "extra credit" is kind of insulting (or maybe just annoyingly cute) when you failed to mention the `Warning message`. (I also don't get that error.) You should have posted the `library` calls that you used to set up your environment. It's also considered poor form on SO to ask multi-pronged questions.

Comment: Ah, apologies, apologies. Just trying to get help understand a solution previously provided on another question for a thorough learning process to improve future use. Happy to take what I can get.

Comment: Do this  `dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)` and then run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't reproduce your error.

```
dat %>%
  na_if("") %>%                                  # Replace "" with NA
  gather("Key", "Val", -type, na.rm = TRUE) %>%  # wide -> long
  rowid_to_column()  %>%                         # Sequentially number rows
  spread(Key, Val, fill = "") %>%                # long -> wide
  select(-1) # works well                        # remove row number
  #        type one two
  #1  chocolate   x
  #2    vanilla   x
  #3 strawberry   x
  #4  chocolate       x
  #5 strawberry       x



dat %>%                                          
  na_if("") %>%                                  # Replace "" with NA
  gather("Key", "Val", -type, na.rm = TRUE)      # wide -> long
#        type Key Val
#1  chocolate one   x
#2    vanilla one   x
#3 strawberry one   x
#4  chocolate two   x
#6 strawberry two   x
```

Explanation:

1. `na_if("")` replaces `""` entries with `NA`.
2. `gather("Key", "Val", -type, na.rm = TRUE)` turns a wide table into a long "key-value" table, by storing entries in all columns *except* `type` in two columns `Key` (i.e. the column name) and `Val` (i.e. the entry). `na.rm = TRUE` removes rows with `NA` values.
3. `rowid_to_column` sequentially numbers the rows.
4. `spread(Key, Val, fill = "")` turns a long "key-value" table into a wide table, with as many columns as there are unique keys in `Key`. Entries are taken from column `Val`, if an entry is missing it's filled with `""`.
5. `select(-1)` removes the first column.

Comment: Thank you!! My R is acting up, so I'll clear my environment again and rerun the code. One follow-up regarding point 3, why do the rows need to be numbered? Does this work as an index/unique key to help the table use spread to turn the df back into a wide table? And lastly, for a thorough understanding - do you mind defining a wide table vs. a long table?

Comment: @S31 I recommend running both examples step-by-step, to understand how the data gets transformed. The row numbering ensures that same `type`s with different `Key`s get spread into different rows. You can see what happens if you don't number the rows: `dat %>% na_if("") %>% gather("Key", "Val", 1:3, na.rm = TRUE) %>% spread(Key, Val, fill = "")`.

Comment: Concerning wide vs. long tables: There are some great resources around. I recommend taking a look at the [`tidyr` documentation](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org); there is also a nice data tidying summary with great visualisations of `spread` and `gather` available [here](http://jules32.github.io/2016-07-12-Oxford/dplyr_tidyr/).

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you @Mauritis

Comment: No worries, glad to help @S31.